# React - unnecessary rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS. I would like to use functional component. In my component, I have a textbox and a clear button.

My concern is - whenever I type a char from my keyboard to enter info for the text box, I see the `search account called!!!` in my console output. If i type 5 chars, I would see this 5 times - it basically means the whole component is re-rendered & methods re-defined.rt?

Is it not bad practice and affect the performance? Is there any other alternative?

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import AccountContext from . './accountContext'

const SearchAccounts = () => {
    
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const onChange = (evt) => setText(evt.target.value);

    console.log('search account called!!!');
    
    // some methods are defined here
    onSubmit = () => {...}
    onClear = () => {...}

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="text" 
                    value={text} 
                    onChange={onChange}
                    placeholder="Search Accounts..." 
                />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" className="...." />
            </form>
            <button 
                className="...."
                onClick={onClear}
                style={getClearStyle()}
            >Clear</button>
        </div>
    );

}

export default SearchAccounts;
```

Comment: The component gets re-rendered depending on your state and props changes. You can setup conditions for if your component should re-render by using the [`shouldComponentUpdate()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). And just a little tip: you can check how much of the DOM is actually re-rendered if you use google chrome "Paint Flashing" (search how to enable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My concern is - whenever I type a char from my keyboard to enter info for the text box, I see the search account called!!! in my console output. If i type 5 chars, I would see this 5 times - it basically means the whole component is re-rendered & methods re-defined.rt?

Yes, this is expected and aligns with the mental model of React.

In React, you'll hear people say "the view is a function of state" — meaning that whatever data you inside of variables in react state should directly determine the rendered output, sometimes refered to as ["one-way data flow"](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

The consequence of doing this however is that, in order to determine what changed, you need to render the react component.

This is fine!

Remember what powers React — the [virtual dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html#what-is-the-virtual-dom). Internally, react creates a light-weight representation of the browser's DOM so that the above one-way data flow is efficient.

---

I see a separate concern here though regarding the amount of time you see the `console.log` output.

What you're doing there is a "side-effect" in React, and whenever you have a side-effect, you should wrap in in `useEffect`. `useEffect` will ensure your side-effect only runs when the values you feed to its dependency array changes.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM

function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('world');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this should only render once');
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`this will render on every value change: the value: ${value}`);
  }, [value])
  
  return (
    <label>
      hello, <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </label>
  );
}

render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

See [here for more on how `useEffect` works](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [here if you want a deep dive](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

Answer (score 1):

Re-renders aren't necessarily expensive, and you have to accept that your components *will* re-render frequently in order propagate the changes in your data to the UI. Your example is very cheap, since the component is small and does not render any additional components in its return function - this is the ideal way to compose React components that have to re-render often.

You have to remember also that your JSX is not trashing and appending all HTML elements to the DOM every time the component re-renders. Only the *difference* between the last render and the current one is being applied, which is what allows React and other front end frameworks to create smooth and fast UIs when built at scale.

If and when you do reach a bottleneck in your components, you can use memoisation techniques (`React.memo` in a functional component context, `shouldComponentUpdate` in a class context) to prevent regularly rendering components from affecting the performance of their component children. It's usually best to do this towards the end of a project or unit of code, and only as a final measure since memoisation escapes built in React optimisation and can actually cause more problems than it solves if you use it inappropriately. A well structured component tree and flux-based state solution will alleviate most performance issues.